# is there a method to match list into other?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, nlp, text-classification

i have a dataframe like :

```
  target   ;  terms
  Sport    ;  Football,Handball, Tennis
  Mécanique ;  voiture, moto, tracteur, bus
  Technologies;  ordinateur, téléphone,tablette, radio, écouteur
```

in input of program i have:

```
list_terms=  ['Football','Handball','ordinateur','tablette','Tennis']
```

expected output :

```
targets : Sport,Technologies
```

Comment: What does `with percentage` mean?

Comment: thnks for your response, it mean , with probability

Comment: please post the expected output column for this sample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply()` on rows and check if `terms` column has any value in entry list.

```py
def check(row):
    targets = [term for term in row['terms'].split(',') if term in entry_list]

    if len(targets) > 0:
        return row['target'] + ' ({:.2f})'.format(len(targets)/len(entry_list))
    else:
        return np.nan

print(df.apply(check, axis=1).dropna().tolist())

"""
['Sport (0.50)', 'Technologies (0.33)']
"""
```

If you don't want probability after target, you could use

```py
def check(row):
    targets = [term for term in row['terms'].split(',') if term in entry_list]
    return len(targets) > 0

print(df[df.apply(check, axis=1)]['target'].tolist())

"""
['Sport', 'Technologies']
"""
```

Comment: thank you but if we want to get probability per 1 i.e in you example : the sum of probability is 0.83

Comment: @Azizoue `eval('+'.join([i.split(' ')[1] for i in ['Sport (0.50)', 'Technologies (0.33)']]))`.